# CREATE MySQL TABLE in PHP with "utf8_unicode_ci"

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, create-table

I need to make a table in php, but i have to set up a "utf8_unicode_ci" coding. Iam using this code:

```
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$userreg."`(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        title VARCHAR(30), 
        rating_estimate INT NOT NULL) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8")
```

but it builds "utf8_general_ci" table. Any advice how to create table in php with unicode coding? thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` after the `CHARSET=utf8` option

Answer (score 1):

add this part after column set :

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

in your case :

```
"CREATE TABLE `".$userreg."`(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(id),
title VARCHAR(30), 
rating_estimate INT NOT NULL) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci "
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

> CREATE TABLE t (c CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin);